# how to save flextable as png in R

Tags: r, png, viewer, flextable

I already followed the recommendation of the link: [R save FlexTable as html file in script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43664234/r-save-flextable-as-html-file-in-script), but it seems that I am facing a different problem, because this solution did not work for me. The `vanilla.table ()` function generates an object other than the `flextable ()` function.

I'm using `flextable` because it allows for desirable formatting possibilities

Example:

```
library(flextable)
library(rtable)

# The example below work.
myft <- vanilla.table(
   head(mtcars) )
myft
writeLines(as.html(myft), "MyFlexTable.html")

# The example below does not work.
myft <- regulartable(
  head(mtcars), 
  col_keys = c("am", "carb", "gear", "mpg", "drat" ))
myft
writeLines(as.html(myft), "MyFlexTable.html")
```

ps: I know it is possible to download the photo manually by clicking on "Export> Save as Image", however I need it programmed

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To save a flextable as a png, you will first need to save it as an html file then to use webshot to get a png from the html file.

````
library(flextable)
myft <- regulartable(
  head(mtcars), 
  col_keys = c("am", "carb", "gear", "mpg", "drat" ))

# create an Rmd file ----
library(rmarkdown)
rmd_name <- tempfile(fileext = ".Rmd")
cat("```{r echo=FALSE}\nmyft\n```", file = rmd_name)

# render as an html file ----
html_name <- tempfile(fileext = ".html")
render(rmd_name, output_format = "html_document", output_file = html_name )

# get a png from the html file with webshot ----
library(webshot)
webshot(html_name, zoom = 2, file = "regulartable.png", 
        selector = "body > div.container-fluid.main-container > div.tabwid > table")
````

[image]

Comment: This method worked perfectly until recently when it fails to capture when text is in **bold**. Using MacOS 10.14.4, webshot 0.5.1 and R 3.5.0.

Comment: use `flextable::save_as_image` and open an issue in GH page if you meet a bug :)