# How can I save a huxtable as png file in R

Tags: r, huxtable, webshot

The `huxtable` package comes with `quick_*` functions to save outputs such as html (via `quick_html`), pdf (via `quick_pdf`) etc.

However, there seems to be no option to directly save to an imgage (e.g. png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this question a while ago and solved it on my own, but thought it may be helpful to others who run into similar challenges.

Fortunately, the package `webshot` allows taking screenshots of `huxtable` outputs saved with `quick_html`.

Here's the solution:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(huxtable)
set.seed(1337)

data <- matrix(rnorm(25), 5, 5)
my_hux <- as_hux(data) %>%
  set_outer_borders(0.4) %>%
  map_background_color(by_rows("grey95", "white")) %>%
  map_text_color(by_quantiles(c(0.1, 0.9), c("red", "black", "green3")))

quick_html(my_hux, file = "ahuxtable.html", open = FALSE)
# higher zoom increases resolution and image size
# you may need to run "webshot::install_phantomjs()" for this to work
webshot::webshot(url = "ahuxtable.html", file = "ahuxtable.png",
                 zoom = 5, selector = "table")
```

There seems to be a similar question with `flextable`, which was solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225669/how-to-save-flextable-as-png-in-r).

Answer (score 1):

Patrick's answer is nice. Alternatively, you can convert the pdf to png with **GhostScript**:

```
gs -sDevice=png16m -sOutputFile="hux.png" hux.pdf
```